# Images are not visible in firefox when browsing through IIS 7

Tags: asp.net, firefox, iis-7

I am designing a web pages in asp.net with visual studio 2008.

When i publish the website and deploy it on iis version 7 and browse the page then this page is showing all of its content like toolbar images in chrome and internet explorer but not showing in firefox. 
And intrestingly when i run the application through vs2008 and browse the page using firefox the page show all of its content and tool bar images.

So what is the problem with using iis? 
 plz help me

Below i am sharing the snapshots of working page using vs2008 and firfox and the non-working page using iis and firefox

Working page [image: working page]![enter image description here]
Non working page [image: non-working page] ![enter image description here]

**Any help will be appreciated**

Comment: No one is there to answer plz help !!!

Comment: Should i remvoe this post no one is there to answer???

Answer (score 0):

IE and Chrome can use windows authentication without any prompt, which is not the case of firefox.
Follow those step to investigate your problem.

1. Check the page source to see if your toolbar is pushed by the
   server.
2. Check if you have any javascript error.  Maybe you have a .js file in a secured directory that chrome and IE can access using windows authentication.

Comment: i am running my script on my local computer and iis is also installed on my local computer.

Comment: and by the way i have told u that when i run the application through vs 2008 using firefox page show all of its content in firefox but problem arise when  i publish the website and deploy it on iis and then  i browse it in firefox problem occurs here.

Comment: You did not put enough information.  Check the page source.  The snapshots you provide did not help.